# How do a deliver data to cooperating aysncio coroutines?

Tags: python-asyncio

I have the following example that works using a zmq socket that gets in data as a coroutine and delivers it to a coroutine that is running an aiohttp client.  I'm simplifying the code:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
async def rcv(addres, msgq):
   init_stuff
   while True:
       msg = await zmq.recv()
       msg.put_nowait(msg)

@asyncio.coroutine
async def send(api, msgq):
   client = aiohttp.ClientSession(api, ...)
   while True:
       msg = await msgq.get()
       resp = await client.post(api, wrap(msg))
```

As I say the above works, what I want is the equivalent of rcv() that reads from a *Queue*, either *queue.Queue*, or *asyncio.Queue*.

I'd be happy if I could put in *msgq* directly.  However, on every path I've tried I get some version of the queue was never awaited or when using *queue.Queue* I simply block.

There is something I am not getting about *asyncio*.  Also, it seems like there are examples out there that don't really work. I.e., they get the same sort of not *awaited* error.  So, I am perhaps confused.

I would love some clarity.  If you can explain what I'm not getting feel free to make fun of me while explaining.  thanks

Comment: Clearly, the subject should have been **cooperating asyncio coroutines**.

Comment: Do you want the same `rcv` implementation to be able to read from `queue.Queue` and `asyncio.Queue`? Or are you saying that you'd like it to be able to read from *some* queue, and either one of the two would suffice?

Comment: Either would work for me. My goals is to integrate this into existing code that is not fast enough.

Comment: Have you tried changing `msg = await zmq.recv()` to `msg = await some_queue.get()`? Your question doesn't really make it clear what is not working for you... perhaps it would help if you posted a more complete (but still short) example that fails to do what you'd like.